# App crashes after splash screen despite trying out all suggestions

Tags: android, exception, android-activity, crash

I'm brand new to Android programming. I am trying to develop an app with a splash screen. Watched a few tutorials & started doing it. The app displays the splash screen but crashes after a few seconds. Tried the suggestions given here on StackExchage, but didn't work. Please have a look at my code before you close this thread as duplicate.

This is my **SplashScreen.java**

```
package collegeproject.mvjce.edu.boat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

/**
 * Created by AURO on 3/6/2016.
 */
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen_layout);

        Thread myThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    Intent startMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(startMain);
                    finish();
                }


            }
        };
        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

This is my **splash_screen_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_screen"
        android:id="@+id/splashView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="collegeproject.mvjce.edu.boat">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my **logcat**

```
03-06 21:38:22.446 18366-18366/collegeproject.mvjce.edu.boat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: collegeproject.mvjce.edu.boat, PID: 18366
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{collegeproject.mvjce.edu.boat/collegeproject.mvjce.edu.boat.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:198)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
                                                                                   at collegeproject.mvjce.edu.boat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

This is my **style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

This is my **style.xml(v21)**

```
<resources>>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I haven't touched MainActivity.java, activity_main.xml & content.xml, hence I haven't given their code here. If you need to have a look, please let me know.

I don't know what the problem seems to be. I have seen over 10 tutorials looking for a fix, have read several threads here on StackExchange & changed my code accordingly, but nothing seemed to have worked. Hence I am posting this question.

Thank You for your time!

Comment: are you using the toolbar in your MainActivity?

Comment: @Blackbelt  I think so because I haven't changed anything in activity_main.xml & content.xml, which are automatically created with the creation of the project. You want me to post the code for them?

Comment: Change `getApplicationContext()` to `YourActivity.this`.

Comment: replace `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`  with `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` in the `<application` tag

Comment: @Blackbelt  Thanks!! That helped!! Could you please tell me why it was being a problem?

Comment: Post your `styles.xml`, `MainActivity.java` and `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: `@style/AppTheme` *has already an actionbar* and in your activity you are either using the `ToolBar`, trying to submit a new `ActionBar` or the `Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR` flag

Comment: @Protino Question edited

Answer (score 1):

This is due to style theme type clash.

Just make these changes to your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And make sure in your `AndroidManifest.xml` application tag's theme attribute is set to `@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar`

You cannot customize your ActionBar by using custom toolbar if you set your style theme as of type `DarkActionBar` or `LightActionBar` or something similar`ActionBar`.

That is why you've to set your theme to `NoActionBar` to make custom changes using functions like `setSuportActionBar(custom_toolbar)`.

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly style theme type clash is? I'm new & this will be useful for me to know. Thanks